# How to make shared Colab notebook able to load h5 files?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I would like to share my work with other people, using a Google Colab shared link, allowing them to edit the code and to run it. Nervertheless, I tried several methods to load a .h5 on Google Colab (even from Google Drive), and the file can be loaded when **I** run the code, but **cannot be loaded when somebody else (other Google account) run the notebook**...

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `keras` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: See [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&ref_topic=7000947) for a possible solution.

Comment: @desertnaut looks promising indeed, thanks !